# Using phpseclib "write" in order to send Linux commands to a web server

Tags: phpseclib

I'm trying to use phpseclib in order to connect SSH to my Web Server through a WEB proxy.
The PHP file is very simple but it doesn't work, what is the problem?

After several seconds while the server seems to hang, the result I get is:

*cd /home/web/sqladmin\nls -la\n*

I tried also using \r\n and \r instead of \n.
The PHP filename is "ssh.php".

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('127.0.0.1');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

?>
<br>
<form action="ssh.php" method="get" name="salvarouting">
Comando: <input name="comando" type="text">
<br><input name="avanti" type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
<br>

<?php 
$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ssh->write('cd /home/web/sqladmin\n');
if(isset($_GET['comando'])) {
    $ssh->write($_GET['comando'].'\n');
    $ssh->setTimeout(10);
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($ssh->read()).'</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I've forgotten to say that the PHP page let the user to issue a command written in an input text box. The result I wrote is related to the 'ls -la' command.

Comment: I've found the problem, I have to use " instead of '.

Comment: Yah - that's exactly it. Case in point: if you do `strlen("\n")` you'll get 1 but if you do `strlen('\n')` you'll get 2.